# How to display custom extension in displacy?

Tags: python, spacy

I want to display custom extension in displacy.
If I use `displacy.serve(doc, style="ent")` it displays entities, but also I have custom extension called 'ner2', I can get it for a token using `token._.ner2`. I want it to be displayed. How do I do this?